# Ivy load info description from file

Tags: ivy

I want to describe my project in ivy.xml,m thats why I added the description field. It looks likes this:

```
...
 <info organisation="blabla" module="blubb" revision="1.7.3-rc3">
  <ivyauthor name="aliceWonderland" />
  <description> Bla ... 
  bla ... 
  bla ... x 10000  = word count
  ....
  many lines ...
 </description>
 </info>
...
```

Does someone know if I can load text from file? My Usecase is, that after publishing via "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using an XML entity to include a file:

- https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/fdp-primer/xml-primer-include.html

Comment: Thx it works. Do you know if it is possible to read the file contents with ommiting first line